# saving text from uitextview to plist

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, uitextview

for my application i am able to read the description of a place selected from the table row and display it in the uitextview. but what i needed to do next is able to save content edited by user in the uitextview to plist. need some guide because i had been searching for it but in vain..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a plist to store a string, you can use -[NSString writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:] method, and just create a single file.

If you're dead set on creating a plist, you can use the NSPropertyListSerialization class to read and write plists.